# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'

Tags: python

В редакторе Visual Studio Code установил командой `pip install click` модуль `click`. Но в первой строке при выполнении `import click` пишет, что модуль не найден. И при выполнении этого же кода в консоли с помощью команды `python 1.py` модуль отрабатывает. Почему в редакторе  Visual Studio Code выдает, что модуль не найден и при выполнении из редактора

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'`
> .

Операционная система у меня Windows 10. Пути в Windows к python прописаны в переменных окружения

```
import click
one = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
two = [4,6,9,11]
three = [2]
month = int(input("Введите номер месяца:"))
if month in one:
    print(31)
elif month in two:
    print(30)
elif month in three:
    print(28)
click.pause('Чтобы продолжить, нажмите Enter.')
```

Comment: Значит через pip установили глобально, а в vscode интерпретатор выбран из виртуального окружения. Или наоборот. Или несколько интерпретаторов установлено.

Comment: Как посмотреть, что установлено несколько интерпретаторов? Я кстати pip install click устнавливал и в директорию, где исполняемый файл пайтона и свой модуль 1.py сюда помещал. Но все равно import click пишет, что модуль не найден

Comment: возможно, что библиотека была скачана не в папку PythonВашаВерсия\Scripts. проверьте, иногда это помогает

Comment: В списке установленных программ можно попробовать посмотреть. Вообще, проверьте что выдаст команда `where python`, и в vscode внизу справа должна быть написана версия python, при наведении покажет путь к интерпретатору. Должен быть тот же путь, что вывел `where python`. Также удалите или отключите расширение "Code Runner", если оно установлено. В какой папке выполняете команду pip install вообще не важно, это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Ваши рекомендации очень помогли! Теперь import click в моем коде отрабатывает. Просмотрел и выполнил все ваши рекомендации. Единственное не уловил после какого шага import click стал виден.